# What should the value of %esp be at this point in the code?

Tags: c, assembly, gnu

I've been having trouble getting this code to work.

```
test    $0x10000000, %esp
jz      .ERROR
ret
```

If it jumps to `.ERROR`, the code just exits. Otherwise the output prints as normal.

When I use `test    $0x0000000, %esp` it quits as I would expect.

These are my sections:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .interp       00000013  08048114  08048114  00000114  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  08048128  08048128  00000128  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .hash         00000038  08048148  08048148  00000148  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .dynsym       00000090  08048180  08048180  00000180  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .dynstr       00000064  08048210  08048210  00000210  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .gnu.version  00000012  08048274  08048274  00000274  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .gnu.version_r 00000020  08048288  08048288  00000288  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .rel.dyn      00000010  080482a8  080482a8  000002a8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .rel.plt      00000030  080482b8  080482b8  000002b8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  9 .init         00000024  080482e8  080482e8  000002e8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 10 .plt          00000070  08048310  08048310  00000310  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 11 .text         00000188  08048380  08048380  00000380  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 12 .springboard  00000023  08048508  08048508  00000508  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 13 .fini         00000015  0804852c  0804852c  0000052c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 14 .rodata       00000024  08048544  08048544  00000544  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 15 .eh_frame     000000e0  08048568  08048568  00000568  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 16 .dynamic      000000c8  08049648  08049648  00000648  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 17 .got          00000004  08049710  08049710  00000710  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 18 .got.plt      00000024  08049714  08049714  00000714  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 19 .data         00000004  08049738  08049738  00000738  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 20 .bss          00000004  0804973c  0804973c  0000073c  2**2
                  ALLOC
 21 .comment      0000002a  00000000  00000000  0000073c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

Maybe I don't understand this yet, but should %esp be equal to addresses in that range?

I can move the .springboard section to 0x10000000 if I link it with my linker script. The return goes to the springboard section. So my thought was that it shouldn't work here, but if I link it with my script and the springboard section is moved, then it will work. Why is it working in both cases?

I'm guessing the test is returning a non-zero value but I don't understand why.

Comment: `test` in x86-assembly performs a bitwise AND on the operands, sets the CPU-flags and discards the result of the AND. So in this case, the code checks whether a specific bit of esp is set. We'd need to see the code to say why.

Comment: @EOF I'm not sure what other code is relevant, but I'd be happy to post it all. I think I should be comparing to the address of the next instruction and not the stack pointer, like Inspired pointed out in his answer. I'm fairly new to assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, esp is a stack pointer, so it should point to some address inside stack. Your program doesn't seem to provide any stack section, so I guess the OS allocates the stack.

Well, if you are about to return from a function, `dword ptr [esp]` (but not esp) should indeed contain an address from the sections above, as this should be an address of the next instruction to be executed after the function call.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `test    $0x80000000, dword ptr [esp]` but it says `Error: junk 'ptr [esp]' after expression
Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction` any idea what I'm doing wrong? I do want to compare to the address of the next instruction I think

Comment: @Matt: `dword ptr  [esp]` is intel-syntax, while `test    $0x10000000, %esp` looks like AT&T-syntax. They don't mix.

Comment: Sorry, I used Intel's assembler syntax, it's a bit different. You should write something like `test $0x80000000, %(esp)` instead (I'm not sure, maybe it's `(%esp)`? You'd know better looking at some other instructions). And possibly you should avoid analyzing a return address at all, usually a well-designed program doesn't require such tricks.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. After changing to `(%esp)`, I got an error saying ` no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands;` and then had to change `test` to `testl`